# Almost all of my programs arn't recognized anymore

Tags: windows-vista, virus

I had a virus on my computer and was able to remove it, however, now almost all of my programs won't work. Even trying to open freecell pulls up the "select a software to run this in" window. I can't even install software anymore because after downloading a setup file and clicking on it, it too opens the "choose a program to run this in" window. I'm trying to find a way to fix without reinstalling the OS. Does anyone know a way to restore the file/files that are missing that are causing this problem without starting over?

Comment: You should associate your accounts; this will give you 100 reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The registry entry for .EXE files has been modified.

You need to boot the computer to a functioning copy of Windows (Such as WinRE on the Vista install CD), run regedit, mount the file `\WINDOWS\system32\config\SOFTWARE`, and set the `(Default)` value of the registry key `Classes\exefile\shell\open\command` to `"%1" %*`.  If it is already, make sure that the `(Default)` value of the key `Classes\.exe` is `exefile`.

Also, (I'm curious), please tell us what that value is now.

I don't think there is any way to do this without a second copy of Windows; however, yuo can try using explorer to copy `Regedit.exe` as regedit.com.

Comment: Caught me writing something similar! +1

Comment: And if I don't have the vista install cd anymore?

Comment: Any install CD for Vista / Windows Server 2008 or later will do, even the trial versions.

Comment: Also, if explorer works (press Windows+E), try copying `regedit.exe` from `WINDOWS\system32` and renaming the copy to end in `.com`; if the copy runs, you can do it there.   (Don't mount any file; replace `Classes` in my instructions with `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. I booted with a copy of windows 7 I had and opened the registry editor, got to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \exefile\shell\open\command and Default and IsolatedCommand both have under the Data header a value of "%1" %* and for the Classes\.exe the Default has exefile in there already. Is there supposed to be anything else in there?

Comment: You're looking at the registry of the functioning copy that you booted to.  You need to load the registry hive from the broken copy by selecting `HKEY_USERS` and clicking File, Load Hive.

Comment: When I try to Load Hive, then follow the same steps above \Windows\system32..... etc and get down to software it asks me for "Key Name:" what am I supposed to put there? the key for the disc I'm booting from or something else?

Comment: Ok so I backed all  of the way out to c:\ then drilled down as directed above when trying to Load Hive and Typed in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for the Key Name and it did it, i think. under Classes_Root I now have a .exe folder which is defaulted to exefile, a exefile folder that has a Default-"Application", EditFlags-"38 07 00 00", and FriendlyTypeName-"@%SystemRoot%\System32\Shell32.dll,-10156" and then a bunch other folders. where should I go from here?

Comment: also the exefile\shell\open\command has default and IsolatedCommand both with data values of "%1" %*

Comment: but the default for the open folder has (value not set)

Comment: also in exefile\shell\runasuser\command the default data value is (value not set)

Comment: You need to browse the key that you loaded under `HKEY_USERS`.  (Not the regular `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key)  Compare the values in the loaded hive (under `HKEY_USERS`) to the known good values in WinPE itself (directly in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`)

Comment: Ok so I did that and everything seems to match. However in the Loaded Hive for the .exe It has a Content Type under Default that isn't is the regular one. It has a Data value of "application/x-msdownload". The loaded Hive .exe also expands and has a "PersistentHandler" folder in it. Should that be there?

Comment: Also, In the original exefile\shell has open,runas,runasuser under it when expanded but the loaded hive's exefile\shell doesn't have the runasuser stuff at all. Do I need to add it? could that be my problem?

Comment: `runasuser` isn't your problem.

Comment: Those are both fine (I have them on my system).

Comment: Did you try running a `.com` file?

Comment: what do you mean "Did you try running a .com file?", I can get onto IE but I don't know what you mean by  .com file.

Comment: In addition to `.exe`, there is another extension for executable files called `.com`.  Copy any EXE, rename it to a `.com`, and see if it works.

Comment: I tried that and couldn't get it to work. I tried changing the shortcut value from .exe to .com and I went into the game program files and made a copy of freecell and changed it to .com and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running the system restore utility to revert your computer's state back to before you had the virus. Do this by:

1. Press windows+r to bring up the run utility
2. type in `rstrui` and hit enter
3. follow the steps and choose an appropriate restore point (windows should make them for you automatically at regular intervals)

Comment: This will not work.  (`rstrui` is an exe file and will not run)

Comment: I thought that would work. Can you boot into safe mode with the command prompt? It is possible to make changes to the registry through the command line. After that you can activate `rstrui` from the command prompt as well.

Comment: You can't – it's an EXE.  Almost anything you can do (including `cmd`) is an exe file.

Comment: Then you'll have to find an install disc and use the repair installation feature from there. This seems the only reasonable solution without going for a complete reinstall.

Comment: No; you can mount and edit the registry from a different copy of Windows.  See my answer.